# Android. How to move the imageview(set position/margin) when it is created

Tags: android, position, imageview, oncreate

I want to put some images in an area at the application start.
As the number of images is not a fixed amount, so I have to create images dynamically.
I want to set the position/margin of every images while they're created for good balance.

I have tried follows, but there is no efficacy.
・After Created, use imageview.layout().
・Use LayoutParams.margins().
・Use AsyncTask to set margins.
・activity.runOnUiThread().

This is the code:

```
    // After access server, if needed then add a imageview to the 'c_box'
    // c_box: the parent that imageview to add.
    FrameLayout c_box = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.c_box);

    MarginLayoutParams mlp = new MarginLayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_file);
    img1.setLayoutParams(params);
    img1.setLongClickable(true);
    img1.setId(img_id);
    c_box.addView(img1);

    img1.setOnTouchListener(listener);


    **// it's possible to set the position by layout or margin?
    img1.layout(100, 100, 200, 200);**
```

I don't know where to call the invalidate() method.

---

```
// After access server, if needed then add a imageview to the 'c_box'
    // c_box: the parent that imageview to add.
    FrameLayout c_box = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.c_box);

    MarginLayoutParams mlp = new MarginLayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mlp.setMargins(100, 100, 200, 200);
    ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.c_file);
    img1.setLayoutParams(mlp);
    img1.setLongClickable(true);
    img1.setId(img_id);
    c_box.addView(img1);

    img1.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the point:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
```

the 3rd param(**Gravity.NO_GRAVITY**) that I missed. use it you can position views at anywhere with setting width/height.

Answer (score 2):

You could use MarginLayoutParams

```
MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) yourImageViewHere.getLayoutParams();
mlp.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);//all in pixels
yourImageViewHere.setLayoutParams(mlp);
```

To set your margins dynamically.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It is possible after a imageview is created and add to the parent?

Comment: Well, I think you would have to redraw your layout if you are setting these margins after onDraw is called.  To force a redraw of your view you could say yourImageViewHere.invalidate(); Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate().  Please accept my answer if this works for you.

Comment: Very thanks. I am glad to accept you answer if this problem is solved.I have edited my question that added some code. any advice?

Comment: Is this in your onCreate method?  You just need to use MarginLayoutParams.  So it would be MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) img1.getLayoutParams();
mlp.setMargins(20, 40, 20, 40);
img1.setLayoutParams(mlp);

Comment: Yes, this is in my onCreate method. and I have tried MarginLayoutParams but nothing is changed. See the question i have edited.

Comment: You didn't add what I wrote.  You added a modified version, that's why it's not working.   Add what I wrote in my pervious comment.

Comment: Hope I wasn't mean in my previous comment. I should say you could try adding what I wrote and maybe it will work, good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my situation, I can't set the init position/margin:　　①the parent of the ImageView is FrameLayout.　　②the imageview can't be defined at the xml before the fact.　　Can you give some test code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot to <<thomas.cloud>> for a long-time reply and patience.

Comment: works great this code to "move" an ImageView in a RelativeLayout using margins, thanks.